# jQuery sortable but work on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am using the jQuery UI Sortable plugin to of course allow my users to drag and drop elements in a list, on the list change I am firing an ajax call to save the ordered list.

However one user is complaining that it is quite hard to drag and drop when the list requires a scroll. So basically what I am attempting to do is instead of the hold left click to drag and then release left click to drop.

You will just left click on the element and it will become the active "drag" element and the user can move their mouse around the screen and it will follow, then on the second left click deactivate "drop" the element.

I have looked at their documentation, but I can't seem to find anything that will help me out (http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/). Does anyone have any ideas or plugins that achieve this?

Regards

Comment: can you add a working snippet?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9sgkavd4/ just simply click and drag an item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help you with this:
'You will just left click on the element and it will become the active "drag" element and the user can move their mouse around the screen and it will follow, then on the second left click deactivate "drop" the element.'

HTML:

```
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$( function() {
  var dragging = false;

    $("#draggable").draggable();
  $("#draggable").mouseup(function(e){
    if(!dragging){
      dragging = true;
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
    else{
      dragging = false;
    }
  })
  } );
```

Codepen example:
http://codepen.io/xszaboj/pen/JWbzax

I hope that is what you need.

Side note. This won't work on touch screen monitors on chrome because of different events which are fired.

Comment: I just tried your codepen example and with just one single left click nothing happens, also this needs to slot an item back into the UL like the JQuery UI Sortable does

Comment: Works for me what browser are you using?

Comment: @Canvas works for me too, I merged his code with yours here : https://jsfiddle.net/9sgkavd4/1/ see if this works for you.

Comment: @Zues I am using chrome, what browser are you using? :) also the fiddle version doesn't work, I can confirm this works in I.E. but this needs to work across browsers

Comment: I am using chrome.. wierd :) I will try to investigate what might be the problem

Comment: My chrome version is 56.0.2924.87, I tell you the truth I have a touch screen monitor, let me try it on another machine, its ok i works perfectly :), its all because my touch monitor must be firing different events, if through I'm using my second monitor which is a standard monitor